# UITextField inside UITableViewCell: becomeFirstResponder in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I am currently trying to get this working. Any help is appreciated.

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that has a `UITextField` inside. When I select the table cell, I would like to make the `UITextField` first Responder.
However  `[textField becomeFirstResponder];` returns **false**.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  UITextField *textField;
  for (UIView *view in [cell subviews]) {
    if ([view isMemberOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
      textField = ((UITextField *)view);
    }
  }

  [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

As requested, the initialisation of the textfield. This is done in the `UITableViewCell` subclass:

```
- (id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
  self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

  if (self) {
    // Init Textfield
    _textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    _textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _textField.delegate = self;
    [self addSubview:_textField];
  }

return self;
}
```

Comment: Is your textField==nil; ? I mean are you able to get the textfield reference ?

Comment: Yes I get the textField reference. The method, becomeFirstResponder, just returns false, since it is for some reason not able to promote the textField to firstResponder.

Comment: Please should us how you create the `UITextField`s. Maybe one of your textfield delegate methods return NO?

Answer (score 16):

If you have a custom cell, then you can do something like this:

```
@implementation CustomCell

#pragma mark - UIResponder

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    return [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Then inside the table view delegate:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([cell canBecomeFirstResponder]) {
        [cell becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @josh-fuggle Thanks for that. The question is one year old. So I can't really remember how I solved it. But this should work!

Comment: Yup, I understand. I just wanted to show another way of solving the problem. I like this design as you can have a few different subviews each responding to UIResponder in different ways, while keeping the same clean code in your table view delegate.

Comment: I am having the same problem and this did not fix it for me.  becomeFirstResponder always returns NO.  Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 3):

Give `tag` for each `UITextField` and and use Following code:

```
UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender.superview.superview;
UITextField *txtField = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:tag];
[txtField becomeFirstResponder];
```

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Its working very good.. :)

Comment: I get the txtField just fine with the method I use, but I tried yours and it sadly does not work either. How is viewWithTag different from what I do? Thanks.

Comment: i m confuse on ur Que.. u add textField on tblViewCell..then how it is call didSelectRowAtIndexPath ?? check by break pint is it run or not ??

Comment: add this method - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

Comment: What does the textFieldShouldReturn method have to do with the becomeFirstResponder?

Comment: this doesnt answer anything. dont waste your time, people.

Comment: @SebastianBorggrewe - you just need to add `[textField resignFirstResponder];`.. its remover you keyboard ;)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to set you `textField`'s `delegate` property.

Add `textField.delegate = self;` to your method, before you call `[textField becomeFirstResponder]`

Comment: The textfield is part of a UITableView cell which is the delegate of the UITextField. However I also tried to call becomeFirstResponder inside the cell class and that does not work either.

Comment: @SebastianBorggrewe That is not good pratice. A UITableViewCell is a view, not a controller. You should set the delegate to be your TableViewController and also make sure that it conforms to the UITextFieldDelegate protocol

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But it still does not explain the becomefirstresponder behaviour, does it?

Comment: @SebastianBorggrewe I thought it should... I don't have my mac so I can't make experiments now. If this isn't solved by the time I get home I will test.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should include a tag value on the textfield when creating the cell:

```
- (id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
      self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

      if (self) {
        // Init Textfield
        _textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        _textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _textField.delegate = self;
        _textField.tag = 999;
        [self addSubview:_textField];
      }

    return self;
}
```

And on the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method use the tag value to recover the object:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:999];


  if (![textField isFirstResponder]){
     [textField becomeFirstResponder];
  }

}
```

I've including a validation to control if the textfield is already the first responder.

Hope it works as you expect

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  UITextField *textField;
  for (id subV in [cell subviews]) {
    if ([subV isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
      textField = (UITextField *)subV;
      [textField becomeFirstResponder];
      break;
    }
  }


}
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the answer from @josh-fuggle to use Swift 2.2.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomTableCell:UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var textValue: UITextField!

    override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return self.textValue.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

And this is in your table view delegate:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        if ((cell?.canBecomeFirstResponder()) != nil) {
            cell?.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
}
```

Comment: Furthermore, you may find it useful to override `isFirstResponder` too, to return whether your text input field is first responder.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(contentViewTapped))
        self.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
    @objc func contentViewTapped() {
        _ = self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

[self.titleLab performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];

Comment: Delaying it is dirty and only causes side effects, that you might not want to have.