# How to make UITextfield firstresponder in UITableview custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have been working on Custom cell in UITableView which is accordion view where I'm inserting rows and deleting row. The issue I'm facing is that when I add a textfield in the cell I'm not able to make it first responder.

Below is my code

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier  =@"filterCell";
    FilterCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"FilterCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

That is my custom cell and grey part is my textfield.

Even when I set `cell.filterTextFields.userInteractionEnabled = NO` and try to make it first responder in the didselectcell method. That also doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: why did you disable filterTextFields user interaction while  you want to respond it ?

Comment: do you mean that keyboard is not getting open when you click `textField` ?

Comment: @gurumandeep Could you add the codes that you have added in UITableView DataSource and Delegate methods

Comment: Please Check textfield delegate is added or not

Comment: if added then set tag to the textfield.Then you can call [textField becomeFirstResponder]; in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: Yes @Lion, keyboard is not opening

Comment: @RajeshDharani i have tried that also but no luck

Comment: Can you show your tried code

Comment: @RajeshDharani i tried to find the cell and then make the text field with tag as the first responder but did not achieve the desired result. You can share your code for the same

Comment: check below link it might be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/15809063/5184217

Comment: Already done that, thanks mate. Not achieving desired result